# runtime error due to Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ubuntu-15.04

I am programming in my Linux machine Ubuntu 14.04. The Other technical specifications are:

> **Machine:** Ubuntu-14.04 LTS
>   **JDK:** JDK-8 (Java EE application)
>   **Webserver:** Apache Tomcat

The Java code given below throws Null Pointer Exception. The error message looks like this:

```
devkrishna@krishna:~/Desktop/Java/project1$ java attempt
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at attempt.main(project1.java:85)
```

The line 85 will be (op[i].get();)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;


class Root{
    public int no=0;
    public String bookNo;
    public String book;
    public String author;
    RandomAccessFile outs;
    public void get(){
        try{
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.print("Enter book no. : ");
            bookNo = in.readLine();
            no = Integer.parseInt(bookNo);
            System.out.print("Enter the book name: ");
            book = in.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter author's name: ");
            author = in.readLine();

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("I/O EXCEPTION !!!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    public void processFile(){
        try{
            outs = new RandomAccessFile("output.dat","rw");
            outs.seek(outs.length());
            outs.writeBytes(bookNo);
            outs.writeBytes("\t \t \t");
            outs.writeBytes(book);
            outs.writeBytes("\t \t \t");
            outs.writeBytes(author);
            outs.writeBytes("\n");
            outs.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("FILE I/O ERROR !!!");
        }
    }
    public void tell(){
        try{
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Book no. : " + bookNo);
            System.out.println("Book name: " + book);
            System.out.println("Author: " + author);
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION !!!");
        }
    }
}

class attempt{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Root op[] = new Root[5];
        for(int i=0;i < 5; i++){
            op[i].get();
            op[i].processFile();
            op[i].tell();
        }
    }
}
```

Implementing this inside main method of `class Attempt`.

```
for(int i=0;i < 5; i++){
    op[i] = new Root(); // here
    op[i].get();
    op[i].processFile();
    op[i].tell();
}
```

throws the compilation errors:

```
devkrishna@krishna:~/Desktop/Java/project1$ javac project1.java
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
project1.java:85: error: ']' expected
                Root op[i]=new Root();
                    ^
project1.java:85: error: illegal start of expression
                Root op[i]=new Root();
                     ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Error has nothing to do with ubuntu. here is simple programming error (and second sample bad pasted from answer), but THEORETICALLY in Java java programming more important is version of Java, IDE etc. Try to give better tag's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're initializing your `Root` array without initializing its elements.

`op[i].get` will be `null` for each `i`, and invoking any method on it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

A simple idiom would be:

```
for(int i=0;i < 5; i++){
    op[i] = new Root(); // here
    op[i].get();
    op[i].processFile();
    op[i].tell();
}
```

An ugly inline alternative would be:

```
Root op[] = new Root[]{new Root(),new Root(),new Root(),new Root(),new Root()};
```

Another ugly inline alternative:

```
Root[] op = {new Root(),new Root(),new Root(),new Root(),new Root()};
```

Finally, the `java.util.Arrays` class has a prettier `fill` method:

```
Root op[] = new Root[5];
java.util.Arrays.fill(op, new Root());
```

However, that will fill your array with the same instance instead of one instance per element, which might not be your desired result.